# Changing location of plugin folder in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, plugins, file-path

I want to change the default location of the plugin folder in QGIS 3.
The reason is that the default location is read-only, but I want to create and use self-made plugins.
Can I change the location somehow?

Comment: Have you tried `Setting > System > Plugin paths`?

Comment: Hi Chris which operating system are you working with? If it's windows you can start QGIS with a batch file. Edit qgis.bat and use the following as the last line: start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qgis-bin.exe" %*  --profiles-path C:\Users\Public\Documents\QGIS3 your plugins folder will be mover to a sub folder of the profiles path folder

Comment: It's Windows 7 & 10, and my QGIS version is 3.8 Zanzibar.
In Plugin paths (you mentioned), I only see C++, but my plugins are in python.
Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we change the location of our plugins folders on Windows by starting QGIS via a batch file. The batch file we use is called qgis.bat and on our QGIS 3.4 install it is located here: C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin

We've changed the last line of the batch file to:

start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qgis-bin.exe" %* --profiles-path C:\Users\Public\Documents\QGIS\

this switches the profiles-path to C:\Users\Public\Documents\QGIS\ which moves the python plugins path to C:\Users\Public\Documents\QGIS\profiles\default\python\plugins when QGIS is started using the qgis.bat file

Comment: I changed the batch file you mentioned, and it worked! Thanks!